# How do I select all polygons in a layer that border 2+ polygons in the same layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, select, data-management

My data consists of equal-sized polygons. I need to identify and select all the polygons that border two or more polygons.

Comment: if they touch, you can always run the topology rule and check the output report (http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/topology_in_arcgis.htm)

Answer (score 2):

If you have ArcGIS for Desktop then I think the **[Polygon Neighbors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000045000000)** tool will provide access to those polygons which have two or more **edge neighbors**.